# Does related subfolders need to be disallowed separately in robots.txt?

Tags: robots.txt

Will disallowing certain folder in robots.txt disallow its related subfolders?
Example:

```
Disallow:/folder/
```

Will match:

```
/folder/page
/folder/subfolder/page
```

Or it will just match:

```
/folder/page
```

So if the second case is true, do I need to disallow second and subsequent subfolder separately?

```
Disallow: /folder/

Disallow  /folder/subfolder/

Disallow /folder/subfolder/onemorefolder
```

Answer (score 0):

Robots.txt has no concept of "folders", it’s just strings. Whatever you specify in `Disallow` is the *beginning* of the URL path.

`Disallow: /` blocks any URL whose path starts with `/` (= all pages).

`Disallow: /foo` blocks any URL whose path starts with `/foo`:

- `/foo`
- `/foobar`
- `/foo.html`
- `/foo/bar`
- `/foo/bar/doe`

`Disallow: /foo/` blocks any URL whose path starts with `/foo/`:

- `/foo/`
- `/foo/bar.html`
- `/foo/bar`
- `/foo/bar/doe`

Comment: Very good explanation. Thanks! 
I believe the same concept is used in bunch of other similar things, like gitignore file for example. I wonder what other special characters are allowed when making you rules, except asterisk.

Comment: @vaseech: The original robots.txt specification doesn’t define *any* special characters with reserved meanings for `Disallow` values. So if you have `Disallow: /foo*`, the `*` is interpreted literally, i.e., URLs that contain the asterisk. However, specific consumers (like the Googlebot) often extend the robots.txt specification and interpret certain characters differently.