# Need to stop indexing the URL parameters for custom build CMS

Tags: robots.txt

I would like for Google to ignore URLs like this:

```
https://www.example.com/blog/category/web-development?page=2
```

As my links are getting indexed in Google I need to stop indexing them. What code should I use to not index them?

This is my curet `robots.txt` file:

```
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /scripts/
Disallow: /privacy
Disallow: /404.html
Disallow: /500.html
Disallow: /tweets
Disallow: /tweet/
```

Can I use this to disallow them?

```
Disallow: /blog/category/*?*
```

Comment: @Machavity: I don’t think that this questions ask for SEO advice. It’s plain specification-based question (to answer the question, only the robots.txt spec + Google’s extension of it are relevant).

Comment: @Machavity it's rare that I disagree with you, but... what unor said.

Comment: Close vote retracted

Answer (score 0):

With robots.txt, you can prevent [crawling, not necessarily indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35524993/1591669).

If you want to disallow Google to crawl URLs

- whose paths start with `/blog/category/`, and
- that contain a query component (e.g., `?`, `?page`, `?page=2`, `?foo=bar&page=2` etc.)

then you can use this:

```
Disallow: /blog/category/*?
```

You don’t need another `*` at the end because `Disallow` values represent [the start](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23386248/1591669) of the URL (beginning from the path).

But note that this is [not supported by all bots](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22156788/1591669). According to the original robots.txt spec, the `*` has no special meaning. Conforming bots would interpret the above line [literally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30412881/1591669) (`*` as part of the path). If you were to follow only the rules from the original specification, you would have to list every occurrence:

```
Disallow: /blog/category/c1?
Disallow: /blog/category/c2?
Disallow: /blog/category/c3?
```